# Non Type object has no attribute get error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get href link from a tag but when I use method `.get` it gives me error "non type object has no attribute get" 
here is my code:

```
#Loading Libraries
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#define URL for scraping
theurl = "http://www.techspot.com/"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)

#Cooking the Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
i=1
#Scraping "Project Title" (project-title)
title = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'article-category'})
for titles in title:

    titleheading = soup.findAll('h2')
    for titletext in titleheading:
        titlename = titletext.a
        titlelink =titlename.get('href')
        print(i)
        print(titlelink)
        i+=1
```

and here is the console screenshot of the error I am getting

[image]

Tell me what's the problem in this code or why i am getting this error

Comment: titlelink is None

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `titletext.a` is `None` before you can use it for sure.

```
for titles in title:
    titleheading = soup.findAll('h2')
    for titletext in titleheading:
        if titletext.a:
            titlename = titletext.a
            titlelink =titlename.get('href')
            print(i)
            print(titlelink)
        i+=1
```

Comment: but stackoverflow do not allow me to mark you solution as answered i don't know why

Comment: @hrmalik You cannot mark it as accepted [before 15 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer).